# Integer field with unix timestamp convert to readable date in views

Tags: views, entities, datetime

I have an Integer field in a content type, which contains a unix timestamp.  *(It is not a date module field; just a simple Integer field).  In a View, I am rendering this field, but obviously it is just going to spit out the long unix timestamp; and I want it to read Feb 20th, 2013.  How can I have Views format this field so that it spits out the readable date?  I imagine I would create the views-view-field--field-MYTIMESTAMP.tpl.php, and copy in the default code, then use some php logic to convert it, right?  But I am not sure how to do that part.

Comment: why cannot you use date module?

Comment: you could also try views php module.

Comment: It comes through a feed from another site.  At this point in time, It can't be changed.

Comment: Why use another module when you have views field tpl files available?

Comment: If you are using feeds module, there is a module - drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper - which allows you to modify the feeds data before saving to db.

Answer (score 2):

First you should define a suitable format- Do this in the administrative GUI:

1. Navigate to: Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Date and Time
2. Click the tab "Formats" and click on link "Add format".
3. Create a new format. You use the same string as you would pass to the PHP [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function, i.e.: `M jS, Y`. Save it.
4. Click the tab "Types". Click on link "Add date type".
5. Select the newly created format from the menu, and name it: `dateonly`, and save it by clicking on "Add date type".

You now have a type of date format named `dateonly` defined you can use *anywhere* on your site there is a date field to be displayed without the hour and minutes part.

To format the date in your View, you may should Drupal [`format_date`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/7) function with `'dateonly'` passed as the type of format to use (second argument). To output this in your view you may have the following in your `view-view-field--fieldname.tpl.php`:

```
<?php
$nicedate = format_date($output, 'dateonly');
print $nicedate;
?>
```

IMHO, there is a big advantage in first defining a standard type of date format and giving it a name.  This ensures that dates are displayed consistently throughot the site.

However, if you can't be bothered to first define the `dateonly` type of format, you can use `custom` as your second argument to `format_date` and then, as your third argument, pass a string that can be passed on to the PHP `date` function:

```
<?php
$nicedate = format_date($output, 'custom', 'M jS, Y');
print $nicedate;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the template for that field as you mentioned, and use the [date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to output a timestamp with the "Feb 20th, 2013" format:

```
print date("M jS, Y", $timestamp);
```

Comment: How would I wrap the views field output (<?php print $output; ?>) in that?

Comment: In your view-view-field--fieldname.tpl.php file the $output variable should hold the timestamp, if so you can just pass $output to the date function:

    `<?php print date("M jS, Y", $output); ?>`